# Check if radio button value exists

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I want to check if a radio button value "birthday" exists and show that radio button (all radios are hidden).
"fl" is a parent div, that contains all radio buttons (I use "fl" many times, that works).
Unfortunately the alert always shows 0 for "radiotoshow.length"
One of the radio buttons in "fl" has the value "birthday" (the radio button text is birthday, I guess it's the value...) but it's not working. Any ideas would be very much appreciated.
I dynamically create the radio buttons in a loop, in liquid (shopify). tagName in one case is "birthday".

HTML:

```
<li  class="sidebarfilters">
   <label class="sidebar-checkboxlabel">
      <input  class="radio-btn" id={{tag | handleize }} type="radio" onClick="" name= {{ ghosttown }}>
        {{ tagName }}
   </label>
</li>
```

JS:

```
var radiotoshow = fl.find("input[type=radio][value='birthday']");
alert(radiotoshow.length);
if (radiotoshow.length > 0) {
  this.show();
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML. Also, there should not be a space between `[type=radio]` and  `[value='birthday']`.

Comment: Thank you @ScottMarcus I deleted the space, but it's still 0 for length

Comment: @Simonski You missed the value attribute in radio input that is why if condition is returning 0/false.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much @KumarGaurav! I thought value is {{tagName}} automatically, so I thought the radio text is always the value :)

Comment: @Simonski My pleasure, but radio value is different than tagname that is just like radio button label.

Comment: so in my case tagName is the label? And I could maybe also just filter for "label" instead of "value"?

Comment: @Simonski yes, you can give it a try but you have to manage array in that case.

Comment: @KumarGaurav I hope you can help me with the part of my code where I want to make the radio button visible. I don't know why $(this).show(); is not working, as I use it in many cases and it's working. Even "fl.find("input[type=radio][value='Geburtstag']").show();" is not working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Found it, it's ...parent().parent().show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is space problem in your code between type and value attribute and check the value of radio button. that is case sensitive.**

```js
var fl = $("#fl");

var radiotoshow = fl.find("input[type=radio][value='Birthday']");
alert(radiotoshow.length);
if (radiotoshow.length > 0) {
  $("#msg").html(`Birthday Radio is available`).show();
}else {
  $("#msg").html(`Birthday Radio is not available`).show();
}
```

```css
#fl input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;
}
#msg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fl">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" id="" value="Birthday">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" id="" value="Sunday">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" id="" value="Friday">
  </div>
  <h1 id="msg"></h1>
  
</body>
</html>
```